# Python function decorator example returning errors

Tags: python

The code below suppose to log the function name, the number of positional arguments and keyword arguments

```
def log(original_function):
def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
    with open("log.txt", "w") as logfile:
        logfile.write("%s,%s,%s" % (log, len(args),len(kwargs.keys())))

    return original_function(*args, **kwargs)

return new_function


def my_function(message):
    print(message) 

>>> my_function = log(my_function)
>>> A = (2,3,4,5)
>>> B = {'Anthony' : 6, 'James' : 7}
>>> my_function(*A, **B)
```

I get this error:

```
 return original_function(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: my_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Anthony'
```

I have gone through the previous pages of the textbook i am learning from and i have followed all the syntax... i seem to think.

Comment: your indentation is wrong. Give the whole `new_function` one more tab in

Comment: also `return new_function` should be indented with one more tab

Comment: and then there are way too many arguments to `my_function`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have edited your code a bit to fix indentation problems and the number of parameters you pass to `my_function` (6 instead of one)

```
def log(original_function):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        with open("log.txt", "w") as logfile:
            logfile.write("%s,%s,%s" % (log, len(args),len(kwargs)))

        return original_function(*args, **kwargs)

    return new_function

def my_function(message):
    print(message)

my_function = log(my_function)
#A = (2,3,4,5)
#B = {'Anthony' : 6, 'James' : 7}
#my_function(*A, **B)
my_function("hello there")
```

produces

```
hello there
```

and

```
cat log.txt
```

produces

```
<function log at 0x7faf64be85f0>,1,0
```

If you were to define `my_function` as

```
def my_function(a, b, c, d, Anthony, James):
    print(a, b, c, d, Anthony, James)
```

then

```
my_function = log(my_function)
A = (2,3,4,5)
B = {'Anthony' : 6, 'James' : 7}
my_function(*A, **B)
```

would produce:

```
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) # in python 2.7; 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 in python3
```

Side note: avoid calling variables with CamelCase, use lowercase instead. Leave CamelCase to class names.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving as parameter of your function `my_function(message)` the following :

```
my_function(2, 3, 4, 5, Anthony=6, James=7)
```

Your decorator looks like this

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Some code
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And then you decorate your function :

```
new_func = decorator(my_function)
```

So  `new_func` is a wrapper of `my_function`. But you are calling the function like this :

```
A = (2, 3, 4, 5)
B = {'Anthony' : 6, 'James' : 7}
new_func(*A, **B)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
new_func(2, 3, 4, 5, Anthony=6, James=7)
```

The stack would look like this :

```
new_func(2, 3, 4, 5, Anthony=6, James=7)
 > wrapper(2, 3, 4, 5, Anthony=6, James=7)
    > my_function(2, 3, 4, 5, Anthony=6, James=7)
```

And `my_function` only allow one parameter : `message`